# Не получается скачать изображение с помощью фреймворка Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Не получается скачать изображение с помощью фреймворка Scrapy.

settings.py:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGE_STORE = '/home/user/project/images'
```

items.py:

```
...
class SampleItem(scrapy.Item):
...
    images = Field()
    image_urls = Field()
```

spiders/basic.py:

```
from project.import SampleItem
...
f = ItemLoader(item=SampleItem(), response=response)
f.add_xpath('image_urls', '//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content')
```

Проверяю в scrapy shell зачение response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content') - ссылка.
При запуске вот такая ошибка появляется:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/user/project/project/spiders/basic.py", line 110, in parse_item
    f.add_xpath('image_urls', '//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 135, in add_xpath
    self.add_value(field_name, values, *processors, **kw)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, как её решить?
Заранее благодарен всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: Откуда Вы скачиваете? Добавьте страничку

Comment: как пример - https://4fresh.ru/products/brav0012